# App crashes in iPad, but no error or cause is displayed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, crash

I'm debugging and right after I press a button, the app just crashes, this is happening only in an iOS device, in web and android it works ok.

The thing is, even if I'm debugging, I got no error in Flash Builder, and in the iPad the app just closes.

Is there a log or something that I can check when something like this happens?, in FB the termination code is 0.

Thanks.

Comment: The only times I have ever had an app crash at runtime without warning were from memory issues or from a buggy ANE (I had an ANE for a cross-platform app that worked only in Android and didn't properly account for iOS). Could you possibly describe what happens when that button is pressed?

Comment: Yeah, the button is inside a flash file, that has a linkage to an SWC file. The code of the button is quite simple, it calls a method defined in the SWC file. 

So, I've placed a trace in the code inside the method that is called when I press the button, and it traces it without problem, but the crash happens right after that, when it attempts to call the method in the SWC file. To check this, I've placed a trace at the beginning of the SWC method, and it doesn't trigger, so I assume that the error happens when it tries to communicate with it.

Comment: you could try Adobe Scout for debugging - should provide more detail on the error (or at least where in code it happens). Are you testing with standard or fast packaging?

Comment: Standard, for some reason I can't test with fast, even if I select it.

Comment: Also, [check the crash logs](http://bjango.com/help/crashlog/) on your device. For example, this is one way to confirm that your app was shut down because it was using too much memory.